# how to trigger CSS over a button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need the button as a trigger for a CSS animation. It is just something basic but I messed it up. What is my mistake? Why did nothing happen when I pressed the button?

```js
function xyz() {
  document.getElementById('box').classList.toggle(active)
}
```

```css
#box {
  position: absolute;
  top: -120%;
  left: 20%;
  width: 60%;
  height: 60%;
  background: #000;
  transition: .5s;
  opacity: 0.7;
}

#box.active {
  top: 20%;
}

#box a {
  font-size: 3em;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
  <a href="#" class="close-box" onclick="closeMenu()">&times;</a>
</div>
<button type="button" onclick="xyz()">Click Me!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that you should specify the classname as a string.

```js
document.getElementById('box').classList.toggle('active')
```

So 'active', between single or double quotes.